# How to test a simple given method using Mockito

Tags: java, testing, mockito, junit5

I am new to testing with java so it confuses me a little how to write a proper unit test to a method with no parameters and return value. In general the snippet looks like the below:

```
public class SplitterService {

private SentenceDAO sentenceObject;
private ObjectToXML objectToXML;
private ObjectToCSV objectToCSV;

public SplitterService(int selector, String inputPath, String outputPath) {
        this(inputPath);
        if (selector == 1)
            objectToCSV = new ObjectToCSV(outputPath, size);
        if (selector == 2)
            objectToXML = new ObjectToXML(outputPath);
    }

public void chooseConverter() {
        if (objectToCSV != null)
            objectToCSV.printRecord(sentenceObject);
        if (objectToXML != null)
            objectToXML.marshal(sentenceObject);
    }
}
```

There are 3 private fields in the class. There is also a constructor which instantiate a given class. Then in the chooseConverter() method a proper action is taken according to the created object.

Could you please give me some advice how to test the chooseConverter method since there is no return value and a parameter (I know Junit 5 and a little of Mockito). Im not looking for any given solution just a few words how to approach my issue.

Comment: I'd question whoever is asking you to test this, and see if you can get them to change the class to use dependency injection.

Comment: You'd mock `ObjectToCSV`'s and `ObjectToXML`'s  related methods and ensure they're called. That said, the "selector" argument to `SplitterService` ctor makes me have a sad, and no clue where `size` comes from. Seems to me this is more like an interface w/ CSV and XML implementations.

Answer (score 1):

The code, in its current form, is not unit-test friendly.
As a last resort, you can test the side effects of ObjectToCSV and ObjectToXML, but lets try to do better than that.

Ideally, the class should provide some injection points to allow you inject new mock instances of ObjectToCSV and ObjectToXML.

- There are multiple ways to introduce DI like providing factories for these objects in a constructor, extracting a factory of SplitterService which injects objectToCSV or objectToXML depending on the selector.
  These methods require some modifications of the client code.
- extracting methods that create instances of objectToCSV and objectToXML from the constructor requires a minimal code change and is transparent to the clients. In such case, you subclass your class and override builder methods to return mocks.
- if no modifications to existing code are allowed, I can recommend pulling in Powermock and mocking the constructors. Note: you must be running junit4 vintage engine, as Powermock hasnt been ported to jUnit5 yet.
  https://dzone.com/articles/using-powermock-mock

Answer (score 0):

you are looking at a few things here... first check that `objectToCSV::printRecord` (`objectToCSV` will be a Mockito mock) is getting called under the condition `objectToCSV != null` (and `objectToXML:: marshal` is getting called under `objectToXML != null`). And also you are looking for `ArgumentCaptor` most probably, that is to test that `objectToCSV::printRecord` and `objectToXML.marshal` is *actually* getting called with `sentenceObject` that you set.